# Blender skin help?

Tags: animation, texturing

I'm doing a Minecraft animation and need help uploading the skin. I know the newest version of Blender doesn't let you replace the image but I'm going to the texture file, deleting it and then opening a new texture file (which is my skin). But it turns out like this...

[image: This]

[image: =]

Answer (score 1):

That's because of the UVs.

You can replace the image by opening whatever texture you want to replace in the UV/Image Editor and Image > Replace Image. You can also do that from where you choose the texture, just look for the path of the new image clicking on the folder icon.

But your problem is happening because of the UVs. Go into the UV/Image Editor and you'll see the UVs don't match with the texture.